# How do I return a value from a scala function?

Tags: scala, loops, return, return-value

I am fairly new to scala and was trying out a few simple things. I created a function that looks something like this:

```
 private def checkValu() : Option[Integer] = {
    if(!list.isEmpty()){
        for(value <-list){
            val x = list.get(0)
        }
    }
    return (x)
  }
```

I call the function in order to return the value x.I access the value of the list and want to return the first value in the list. But somehow this does not seem to work. It gives me an error saying

```
"not found value x".
```

I also tried doing without the "return" statment, but then it gives me errors at the if and for loop saying

```
"type mismatch; found : Unit required: Option[Integer]"
```

What am I missing here? Could seombody please help me here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/

Comment: It's not javascript. The scope of x is the block it is in, not the containing function.

Comment: Why is this voted down 4 times? This is clearly someone who is a) trying b) new to the language and c) at the right website to get help. There is nothing inflammatory and the example contains code.

Comment: @wheaties I think it would need some clarification what is the expected result. (I also see the positive parts, that is why I decided to answer it, though I can understand those who have down-voted it too.)

Comment: @GáborBakos Glad you answered. I think the general problem with people new to a subject is that they don't know how to ask what they don't know because they know so little.

Comment: @wheaties : Thanks for those kind words of encouragment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
 def checkValue() : Option[Integer] = {
    if(!list.isEmpty()) {//Assuming list is java.util.List[Integer] and want the last value
        return Some(list.get(list.size() - 1))
    }
    None
 }
```

This solution uses `java.util.List<Integer>`, I guess you used that for `list`. `None` is simply returned when no values are present, otherwise, the last, though I was not sure that was your intention, in case you want the first: `return Some(list.get(0))`

A more idiomatic solution:

```
 def checkValue() : Option[Integer] = {
    if(!list.isEmpty()) {//Assuming list is java.util.List[Integer] and first value is required
        Some(list.get(0))
    } else {
        None
    }
 }
```

I was unsure which value you wanted to return because you wanted to loop through the whole list (naming of the method did not help either). Probably @cmbaxter was right and you wanted the first one.

Just some notes about the error messages: first: you were referring to a variable `x` that was out of scope (outside of the for comprehension), so it was not a good choice. The second one was probably caused by because of the `if` statement without else, which results in `Unit`. As that remain the only expression, that was tried to be returned, though that was not an `Option[Integer]`.

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking for the last item (which could be easily satisfied with `lastOption`) as they keep getting the 0th index each time the loop through the list.  I think what they want is `headOption`

Comment: @cmbaxter I think the OP uses `java.util.List`, so no `lastOption` or `headOption` unless there is an implicit conversion, though I think that would be more confusing for her/him.

Comment: there is `import JavaConverters._` then you can get the scala API with `list.asScala.lastOption`

Comment: @fommil yes, that is true, though that was even less resembling to the original code -which did not state what should do- than my suggestion. It is possible I am on a totally wrong track as this question was tagged as [loop], though it does not need loops imho.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this be easier:

```
def checkValue(): Option[Int] = list.headOption 
// assuming list is List[Int] and you want to return option of the first element
```